# How would you draw wood encased in clear epoxy?

Tags: rendering, texturing, sculpting, glass

I am trying to create a table that has wood encased in epoxy. Some of the ways I thought of was to draw a wood plank than merge it with a glass top. Not have much luck doing this. Looking for any suggestions on the best way to approach this. I also am drawing voids and cracks in the wood. I will be adding a clear glass/epoxy to these voids.

Comment: How about putting the piece of wood  into another object with a larger volume that has an epoxy material applied?

Comment: just for understanding, is this a drawing question or a Blender shading question?

Comment: Blender question. rjg how do you apply epoxy material? I want it to be clear - do I use a glass material? So, I am thinking I create two objects one wood and the other glass then I move the wood into the glass. Is there a join? Can I see the edge of the wood in the glass?